# JQuery remove event handler in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe

I need to remove an event handler in an iframe and replace it with a different one using JQuery 1.7.1.

I now I should use .off(event). However, it doesn't work in an iframe, only in a single document.

Example:

In the iframe (#iframe) is:

```
$('#div').on('click', doSomething);
```

In the parent document is:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('#div').off('click').on('click', doSomethingElse);
```

This adds the new event, however, it doesn't remove the original event.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you add the original event or was it part of the script running via the `<iframe>`. More specifically was the parent script responsible for adding the event?

Comment: No the original event was set in the iframe document itself.

Comment: Agreeing with @War10ck. If the conditions of the to be removed event aren't exactly the same removing the event will fail.

Comment: I could be wrong on this but I believe jQuery creates a pointer (generated id of some sorts) to events it creates meaning the document script will hold the pointer, not the parent instance of jQuery. Since the parent instance has no pointer, it probably doesn't know which events the element has and which one's it can remove. Don't hold me to this as it could be wrong. That's how I've always understood jQuery to work though.

Comment: So there is no way how to do it?

Comment: If the above understanding is correct, no.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to deal with it different way.

Comment: [Here](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#8) is a good resource that verifies the above claim that jQuery keeps information internal to each event. See the current slide and the next one below...

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `off()` using iframe window's jQuery which is accessible through `contentWindow`. Something like this worked for me:

`var iframeWindow = $('iframe').eq(0)[0].contentWindow;`
`iframeWindow.$(iframeWindow).off();`

Answer (score 0):

Does the iframe contain an external resource? Then it is impossible, cause of: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: No, it's the same origin.